# Tikz Paths in Automata

Tags: automata, tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw an automata in LaTeX with TikZ, but I don't know how to make a long transition between two states. I need a sized label to be placed on it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 

   \node[state,initial] (s_0)   {Start 1}; 
   \node[state] (s_1) [right=of s_0] {Start 2}; 
   \node[state] (s_2) [right=of s_1] {Start 3};



    \path[->] 
    (s_0) edge [bend left] node {Path not long enough for text} (s_1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Gives this result:

[image]

Anyone here who could help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: In your case, you could simply increase the node distance: `\node[state, right=5cm of s_0] (s_1) {Start 2};` and/or reduce the width of the node on the path: `\path[->] (s_0) edge [bend left] node[align=center, text width=5cm] {Path not long enough for text} (s_1);`

Answer (score 8):

Choose your option.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
  \node[state,initial] (s_0)   {Start 1}; 
  \node[state] (s_1) [right=of s_0] {Start 2}; 
  \node[state] (s_2) [right=of s_1] {Start 3};

  \path[->] (s_0) edge [bend left] node[text width=1.5cm,
                                        align=center
                                       ] {Path not long enough for text} (s_1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
  \node[state,initial] (s_0)   {Start 1}; 
  \node[state] (s_1) [right=4cm of s_0] {Start 2};% or [node distance=4cm, right=of s_0]
  \node[state] (s_2) [right=of s_1] {Start 3};

  \path[->] (s_0) edge [bend left] node {Path not long enough for text} (s_1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Comment: the second option only works because you hard coded `4cm`. That will not work with text that is not that wide. Is there a generic solution that adjusts the distance between nodes to fit the text on a path?